# Android Outgoing call block issue

Tags: android

I am creating an android application in which following functionality needed-

when user open android dialpad or contact list,and try to call any number there should be an alert dialog appear with yes and no button.

if user click yes button then call connect.

if user click no button then call disconnect.

during the period when alert dialog show and user do nothing then call not connect in background.

If you have any idea please suggest me how to do this.??

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question currently. You need to taken action after user gives input on alert dialog box. If yes then try to implement your code on Click Event of button show in dialog box

Comment: You are right but i need alert when user want to outgoing call.

Comment: Are you implementing your own dialog box. Implement dialog box that act as alert. On getting user input, take appropriate action as suggested.

Comment: Please read question carefully.i know how to use alert dialog or custom dialog.my question is when want to call from dialpad then how alert dialog show..???

Comment: Can you post your code here. that will give more clarity. If you are calling ACTION_DIAL and starting dialer activity. Then i think you are moving out of scope of your application. But if you are calling ACTION_CALL from your activity then this can be handled on dialog box on click .